# Two stage lookup for operator<<

Tags: c++, templates

Currently I am trying to overload the insertion operator `<<` for a class I was working on. For some reason I split it up into two functions and called one from the other. After switching to templates, it didn't work anymore. After looking up the problem, I found out about [two stage lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922668/6608142) and [some reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12561834/6608142) behind it.

Essentially, what I was trying to do is the following:

```
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
class MyClass {
public:
  using foo_t = Foo;
  using bar_t = Bar;

  bar_t some_func() const { /* do something */ }
};

/* Level 2 operator */
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const typename MyClass<Foo,Bar>::bar_t& bar) {
  return out << some_other_func(bar);
}

/* Level 1 operator calls level 2 operator */
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass<Foo,Bar>& myClass) {
  return out << myClass.some_func();
}
```

Unfortunately, due to the fact that `bar_t` is dependent, this does not compile which had me change the level 1 operator to the following:

```
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass<Foo,Bar>& myClass) {
  return operator<<<Foo,Bar>(out,myClass.some_func());
}
```

Now this is arguably not very beautiful and in my opinion obliterates the purpose of the `<<` operator.

Besides the obvious solution of not splitting the two operators, does anybody have a nice solution to this?

Comment: In what you call "level 2 operator", `Foo` and `Bar` are [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). You can only call this function if you provide type parameters explicitly.

Comment: I don't really see the need for the "level 2" output operator? Why not simply use standard overloading for the possible alternatives of `Bar`? Like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const OneTypeOfBar& bar);`? No special handling needed for the "level 1" operator function.

Comment: I was thinking of specializing, too. But then I am losing all the gains I wanted to achieve with templatization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are describing has nothing to do with two-step lookup. Instead, it has to do with the fact that in the function

```
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const typename MyClass<Foo,Bar>::bar_t& bar)
```

`Foo` and `Bar` are in non-deduced context. It means, that you have to provide those template arguments every time you call the function.

As to while compiler can't deduce types here, let's consider a simpler example of the same thing which would not work:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    using type = int;
    type i = 42;
};

template<class T> void foo(typename A<T>::type );
...
A<void*> a;
foo(a.i); // problematic call
```

You would want `T` to be deduced to `void*` in the example above. However, type of `a.i` is int. So that call is identical to

```
foo(int(42));
```

Obviously, there is no meaningful `T` compiler can deduce here.

As to how to solve this problem - try not to use non-deduced types with streams. If you can't, than probably stream insertion operators are not a good fit for this, as the syntax is really ugly. Just use normal functions.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So the types `Foo` and `Bar` are not automatically deduced. Do you have a suggestion on how to solve the problem while still keeping the flexibility of templates?

Comment: @KorbenDose I do not now any good solution, added some general wording.

Comment: Your example made it a lot clearer as to why the compiler can't deduce the appropriate types. Thanks.